# AEM6.2: How to store an xml file under content node which is created using JAXB

Tags: aem

I am reading properties stored in the content node(mypage.html) and creating an xml with those values(using JAXB). Now i have a requirement to store that xml file under the content node. How do i meet this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

While the best solution would be to create the xml on the fly when that page is requested with a special selector, I do not know your exact reason for why you need to create an xml file. Regardless, here is how you do it:
Using [JcrUtils#putFile](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.8/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html#putFile(javax.jcr.Node,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.InputStream))

```
JcrUtils.putFile(yourPageContentNode, “someFile.xml”, “application/xml”, yourFileInputStream)
```